# how is the inverse Hankel transform defined

Tags: functional-analysis, special-functions, integral-transforms

The finite Hankel transform in my notes is defined as
$$
f^*(k_i) = \int_{0}^{\infty} {r f(r)J_0(rk_i)dr},
$$
where $k_i$ is one of the positive roots of $J_0$. However, my notes don't say anything about the inverse transform (?!). This is what I found [online](http://books.google.dk/books?id=9KHw6R8rQEMC&pg=PA477&lpg=PA477&dq=hankel%20transform%20inverse%20how&source=bl&ots=EH4aoxXcEu&sig=_S10baO2YAUivLqR6tlODZdr1zY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5-bwUvmhL4jpywPng4LoCw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=hankel%20transform%20inverse%20how&f=false):
$$
f(r) = \int_{0}^{\infty}{k_iJ_0(k_ir)f^*(k_i)dk_i}
$$
This doesn't make sense to me as $k_i$ are a discrete set. So how I can integrate over them? Shouldn't it be a sum instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hankel transform is (when it is invertible) the same as its inverse. It is an involution.

Hence, your formula is correct, just your interpretation of $k_i$ is incorrect. It is just a variable and has nothing to do with zeros of the Bessel function.

EDIT: There is another related mathematical construct, called the Fourier Bessel series http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Fourier-BesselSeries.html, which has coeffs

$$A_i = \frac{2}{J_{n+1}(k_i)^2} \int_0^1 r f(r) J_n(k_i r) \mathrm{d} r$$

and

$$f(r) = \sum_i A_i J_n(k_i r),  \quad \text{ for } \quad 0 \leq x < 1$$
There the $k_i$ are the positive roots of $J_n$.

Apparently the paper you are citing, defines this Fourier Bessel Series as finite Hankel transform (with slight coefficient change $f^*(i) = \frac{J_{n+1}(k_i)^2}{2} A_i$, but nontheless the same mathematical idea).

I never have heard of name "finite Hankel transform" before, and knew this as Fourier Bessel series. I agree that the coefficient change makes it very similar to the normal Hankel transform, which just has the upper integral bound as $\infty$ instead of $1$.

But note that in the original post you have $\infty$ as upper bound, which makes that, what you present, the normal Hankel transform and not the finite transform.

Comment: Well, my notes say that $k_i$ are positive roots of $J_0$.

Comment: well, then your notes must be incorrect :). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_transform is quite clear about the inverse transform.

Answer (score 0):

Found a paper here that describes the finite Hankel transform and its inverse: http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102867723

My notes were right :-)

Comment: Well, your original question is not about the finite Hankel transform. Is that where your confusion is coming from?

Comment: Yes, exactly right Andreas

Comment: see my updated answer. I added something on the finite Hankel transform to make the distinction clear.